# Azure Price API

Tags: azure, servicenow-rest-api

We are using Azue retail price api in ServiceNow to get the Azure services prices. It was working for us before and was giving all the results. Now it is giving us below error:

"Request not sent to uri= https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices : org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException: Session contains no certificates - Untrusted"

Can anyone help me with this issue?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices

Comment: looks like the certificate expired. This is not a question for StackOverflow but rather maybe for Azure Support

Comment: the problem was solved by Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is fixed now, but ran into the same issue earlier. The certificate was not expired, but Azure replaced the certificate with one signed by an internal (untrusted) certificate authority. Looks like they have replaced it with a DigiCert-signed certificate so your requests should work again.